# Correct way to break out of if statement within for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the correct way of breaking out of a nested if statement/for loop? I have tried the following approach but the preferred approach does not work:

**service.js - NOT WORKING but better because it breaks out as soon as a match is found**

```
    getSelectedService: function(serviceId) {
        serviceId = parseInt(serviceId);
        for(i=0;i<servicesData.length;i++) {
            if(servicesData[i].id === serviceId) {
                var service = servicesData[i];
                return service;
            }
        }
    }
```

**services.js - WORKING but not good as it loops through everything even when a match is found**

```
getSelectedService: function(serviceId) {
    serviceId = parseInt(serviceId);
    servicesData.forEach(function(service) {
        if(service.id === serviceId) {
            var selectedService = service;                  
        }
    });
    return selectedService;
}
```

Comment: The first code returns the first matched service, the second returns the last matched service. It's not obvious what "NOT WORKING" means. They are equivalent and most likely identical.

Comment: Use `filter`. `getSelectedService: function(serviceId) {
    serviceId = parseInt(serviceId);
    var service = servicesData.filter(service => service.id === serviceId);

    return service.length ? service[0] : {};
}`

Comment: @Tushar why would one prefer your suggestion over the first code example? And as soon as you use ES2015 - why not use `Array.prototype.find()`?

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the response. I asked a question earlier on regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845292/share-data-between-controllers-in-ionic-framework-angular-js. I hope it may provide more context.

Comment: @methuselah no it does not - what "NOT WORKING" means? Those 2 implementations are equivalent and work the same. If you tried to run them in isolation you would see that.

Comment: @zerkms I am trying to use method getSelectedService to search ServicesData for a particular id and inject ServicesData to ServiceCtrl, which then appears on a different page. When I say not working, it means that I do not get the data appearing on the second page (service.html).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q4s85vfm/ --- your first code works for sure.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/how-to-short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: "it means that I do not get the data appearing on the second page" --- the problem is somewhere else then, both your code samples are identical and both work fine.

Comment: @zerkms you're right. I looked elsewhere and found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop on the first match, you shoud use a while loop.

```
var keepGoing = true;
var i = 0;
var service;

while( keepGoing && i < servicesData.length ) {
    if( servicesData[i].id === serviceId ) {
        service = servicesData[i];
        keepGoing = false;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}

return service;
```

Comment: @methuselah - There's no fundamental reason a `while` loop is better than a `for` loop for this purpose.  The two can be used fairly interchangeably.  You can break out of a `for` loop with `break` or `return` just fine.

Comment: I agree, I just gave an answer different from the solutions he tried.